# Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 but different hdd

Tags: dual-boot

I have two drives. First is an SSD Installd Ubuntu 22.04. Is it possible to install the external drive windows 10 to dual boot it with Ubuntu? If yes how?

Comment: You can dual boot Windows & Ubuntu on different drives. But Windows does not work from external drives. Its license is for one computer, so has to be installed on internal drive. Always boot all systems in same boot mode, and most are now UEFI on gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: @oldfred: Rufus will create a working Windows-To-Go USB. I last tested it a year ago with Win10_20H2_English_x64. I could find nothing on the Windows site saying it is illegal, (they created it). They say it does not work with versions later than 1903 but that is false.

Comment: @Cserés Szabolcs: Your Windows is likely EFI. If so and your Ubuntu is also installed UEFI, just run `sudo update-grub` from Terminal and it will add Windows to your GRUB bootloader.